# nginx, django and x_requested_with: request.is_ajax() returns False

Tags: django, http, nginx

I've got this code in my Django view:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.raw_post_data)
```

And I send this request, via CURL:

```
curl -v -i -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest" -X POST -d '{"tweet_id":"189881044923719680", "question_id":"1", "choice_one":"T", "choice_two":"F", "choice_three":"F", "extra_passback":"common cold"}' http://ec[...].compute-1.amazonaws.com/question/answer/
```

This works when I hit my development Django server. In production I'm running nginx and gunicorn. And the curl statement doesn't work.

request.is_ajax() returns False (is_ajax looks for the x_requested_with header).

I think this must have to do with an NGINX configuration perhaps. But I'm not sure. What do I need to change?

Comment: Try this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass_header

Answer (score 2):

Try to change the underscores in `X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest` with dashes: `X-REQUESTED-WITH:XMLHttpRequest`.

I had the same problem with nginx as proxy deleted the `X_REQUESTED_WITH` field from the request. Per default nginx marks headers with underscores as invalid and ignores invalid headers.

You can use nginx directives to either allow underscores in headers with `underscores_in_headers on;` or don't ignore invalid header with `ignore_invalid_headers off;`.

In my concrete case I used python requests as client, django as server and nginx as proxy and solved my problem in which I renamed `X_REQUESTED_WITH` to `X-REQUESTED-WITH`. (Django automatically adds `'HTTP_'` to the start of x-header names before making the header available in `request.META.`)

```
import requests
headers = {'X-REQUESTED-WITH':'XMLHttpRequest'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```